# AWS RDS MySQL replication from 5.6 to 5.7 during the upgrade process

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication, mysqlupgrade

**Context**

Hi all,
we are about to upgrade our AWS RDS MySQL instance from MySQL 5.6 to MySQL 5.7.
To do so, we are planning to go through the following steps

1. Create a read replica of the primary instance
2. Upgrade the read replica version from 5.6 to 5.7
3. Stop write operations on the primary instance
4. Wait until all the data is replicated
5. Promote the read replica to be the master
6. Update our DB DNS record to point to the replica endpoint

**Question**

According to the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.MySQL.html#USER_UpgradeDBInstance.MySQL.DateTime57) the **DateTime**, **Time** and **Timestamp** data type has changed between MySQL 5.6 and MySQL 5.7. That's why I wonder if the replication will still work between the primary (MySQL 5.6) and the upgraded replica (MySQL 5.7) in step "4"?

Since the primary instance will still use the old **DateTime**, **Time** and **Timestamp** format, what will happen in the replica that uses the new format?

Will the data be replicated using the old format or will it be converted to fit with the new format?

Thanks

Comment: Hi there,
Did you face any issue with the mentioned approach ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, replication works. If replication will not work then it will raise an error which can be visible by running "show slave status \G" query in MySQL prompt. We have upgraded our RDS instances by following the same steps as you mentioned and we didn't encounter any issues so far.